# What's the difference between these two operations?

Tags: black-holes, black-hole-thermodynamics

Assuming we have a black hole with mass $M$, we have two different operations on it:

(1) Let the black hole to radiate for a while (before Page time) and collect all the radiation and collapse the radiation into another black hole. So we have two black holes with masses $M1+M2=M$

(2) Directly divide the original black hole into two smaller black holes with masses $M1+M2=M$

So (1) is a detour to achieve (2).

Questions:

- The operation (2) will be difficult(with a very low success probability) since splitting the black hole is an entropy decrease process. But there is no principle to forbid this to happen on a black hole with a very low probability. Is this correct?
- Will the first operation also be difficult? Collecting all the radiation is possible in principle, but can we squeeze the radiation into a black hole? If so, why? If not, why?
- What's the difference between the results of these two operations if they can be carried out? Will both of them result in two entangled black holes?

Comment: (Note that, since it has confused users in the past, that I'm not CuriousOne) What do you mean by "having those operations", and what is your measure of their "difficulty"? We don't have actual black holes in actual labs that we can divide with actual devices, so this cannot be a question about experimental difficulty. What, then, is your precise notion of "difficulty" here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind 'Difficulty' might be 'low probability of success', for example, a black hole might spontaneously split into two smaller black holes, though the probability is really low. So any designed protocol to achieve the task will be 'difficult'. At least, black hole splitting will decrease the entropy, so a rare event.